# How to stack two img tags when centered

Tags: css, image, html, cover

I am trying to place two img tags onto of each other but have them both centered.

Here is where im trying to do it: http://nathanturnbull.me/scrolldiv/home.html

The Html:

```
<div id="divs" class="div1">
    <div class="textcont">
        <img class="imglogo" src="gpk.gif" alt="GPK NET">
        <div class="textcont" >
            <img class="imgbutton" src="gpk.gif">
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The css:

```
#divs, #div4 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Cousine';
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
    display: table;
}

.textcont {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.imgbutton {
    height: 42px;
    width: 84px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.container IMG {
    display: inline; /* browser default */
}
```

or

```
IMG {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Your images should be horizontally centred inside their container.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display:table-cell;` statement from your `.textcont` CSS class.

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/FAEF3/1/)

Comment: This does work but now the images sit at the top of the page rather than being in the middle. How do I fix this?